# trouble with local time

Tags: java, android, time, local

i use these codes to get my local time:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar currenDdate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.print("Last update: "+dateFormat.format(currenDdate.getTime()));
```

or:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar currenDdate = Calendar.getInstance(getTimeZone("GMT+3.5"));
System.out.print("Last update: "+dateFormat.format(currenDdate.getTime()));
```

but non of them give the local time, they are both giving me GMT
what is the problem?

NOTE: I am using eclipse and android programming, the codes above correctly work in java but in android it is not!

instead of system.out.print() i use a textview to show the time

```
TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gold_textView1);
date.setText("Last update: "+dateFormat.format(currenDdate.getTime()));
```

please help me find the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try `Date currentDate = new Date()` instead of the `Calendar` object.  Your `System.out.print()` call won't change.  Also, double check your system to make sure its default timezone is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Calendar currenDdate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out
    .print("Last update: " + dateFormat.format(currenDdate.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Calendar` you need to set your `TimeZone` on `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0330"));

// prints: Last update: 2013/07/31 18:46:24 +0330
System.out.println("Last update: " + dateFormat2.format(currenDdate.getTime()));
```

This is required because `SimpleDateFormat` uses a `Calendar` instance of its own internally.

See [SimpleDateFormat#setTimeZone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29)

```
public void setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)
{
    calendar.setTimeZone(zone);
}
```

Notice, the date format pattern also includes the time zone letter `Z` to include it in the display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use JodaTime http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZoneUTC = DateTimeZone.UTC;
DateTime dateTimeUTC = new DateTime().withZone(dateTimeZoneUTC);

DateTimeZone dateTimeZoneLocal = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
DateTime dateTimeLocal = dateTimeUTC.withZone(dateTimeZoneLocal);

DateTimeZone dateTimeZoneOffset = DateTimeZone.forID("-03:00");
DateTime dateTimeOffset = dateTimeLocal.withZone(dateTimeZoneOffset);

// Airport Current Time hh/mm
DateTimeFormatter timeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh/mm").withZone(dateTimeZoneOffset);
currentTime.setText(timeFormat.print(dateTimeOffset));
```